# How can I get the previous comment element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a word document which I saved as single page web HTML file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="WordSection2">
 <p class="Special">
  <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight:normal"><span style="font-size: 14.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">Table of Contents<o:p></o:p></span></b>
 </p>
 <p class="MsoToc1">
  <!--[if supportFields]><span style='mso-element:field-begin'></span><span
style='mso-spacerun:yes'>&nbsp;</span>TOC \o &quot;1-4&quot; <span style='mso-element:
field-separator'></span><![endif]-->
  1. Introduction<span style="mso-tab-count: 1 dotted">.......................................................................................................................................... </span>
  <!--[if supportFields]><span
style='mso-element:field-begin'></span> PAGEREF _Toc251612863 \h <span
style='mso-element:field-separator'></span><![endif]-->
  1
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:data>08D0C</w:data>
</xml><![endif]-->
  <!--[if supportFields]><span style='mso-element:field-end'></span><![endif]-->
  <span style="mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;font-weight: normal"><o:p></o:p></span>
 </p>
 <p class="MsoToc2">
  1.1 Hello world<span style="mso-tab-count:1 dotted">......................................................................................................................................... </span>
  <!--[if supportFields]><span
style='mso-element:field-begin'></span> PAGEREF _Toc251612864 \h <span
style='mso-element:field-separator'></span><![endif]-->
  2
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:data>08D0C9EA79F9BACE118C8200AA004BA90B02000000080000000E0000005F0054006F0063003200350031003600310032003800360034000000</w:data>
</xml><![endif]-->
  <!--[if supportFields]><span style='mso-element:field-end'></span><![endif]-->
  <span style="mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;"><o:p></o:p></span>
 </p>
 <p class="MsoToc2">
  1.2 Program structure<span style="mso-tab-count:1 dotted">............................................................................................................................... </span>
  <!--[if supportFields]><span
style='mso-element:field-begin'></span> PAGEREF _Toc251612865 \h <span
style='mso-element:field-separator'></span><![endif]-->
  3
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:data>08D0C9EA79F9BACE118C8200AA004BA90B02000000080000000E0000005F0054006F0063003200350031003600310032003800360035000000</w:data>
</xml><![endif]-->
  <!--[if supportFields]><span style='mso-element:field-end'></span><![endif]-->
  <span style="mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;"><o:p></o:p></span>
 </p>
 <p class="MsoToc2">
  1.3 Types and variables<span style="mso-tab-count:1 dotted">............................................................................................................................. </span>
  <!--[if supportFields]><span
style='mso-element:field-begin'></span> PAGEREF _Toc251612866 \h <span
style='mso-element:field-separator'></span><![endif]-->
  4
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:data>08D0C9EA79F9BACE118C8200AA004BA90B02000000080000000E0000005F0054006F0063003200350031003600310032003800360036000000</w:data>
</xml><![endif]-->
  <!--[if supportFields]><span style='mso-element:field-end'></span><![endif]-->
  <span style="mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;"><o:p></o:p></span>
 </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

[(jsbin is here)](http://jsbin.com/dagas/edit?html,output)

I want to wrap the right side numbers as *Anchors* (`<a href="#..." >`) to redirect to another part of the document.

By right side numbers I mean :

[image]

So ,  looking at the html structure :

[image]

**Question:**

I want to wrap `1` as `<a href="#_toc25162863" >1</a>`

and

I want to wrap `2` as `<a href="#_toc251612864" >2</a>`

There is no problem getting the `1` with jQuery , but How can I get `_Tocxxxx` from the *previous remark element* of the `1` value ?

Comment: I dont understand why someone downvoted this question (that canceled my upvote).

Comment: « This question shows research effort; it is usefull and clear » ... I think it is the case. You dont upvote it, ok, but why downvote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsbin.com/gofefe/4/edit?html,js,console,output

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refStartWith =  '_Toc|_Ref';
    var regex = new RegExp('(PAGEREF|REF)[\s\n\r ]*?('+refStartWith+')');

    $(".WordSection2 [class^=MsoToc],[class^=MsoNormal],[class^=MsoListBullet]").each(function(i,e){ // apply to your elements instead of body
        $(e).contents().filter(function(){

        return this.nodeType == 8; // select only comments

    }).filter(function(){
        var that = this;
        var matching = that.nodeValue.match(regex);
        if(matching){
            $.each(matching.input.split(/[\r\n \t]/),function(i,e){
                if(e.match(/^(_Toc|_Ref)/)) that.myref = e; // Define the correct ref to set the futue anchor id
            });
        } 
        return matching;

    }).each(function(i, e){

        var wrapper_id = '#_' + e.myref.charAt(1) + e.myref.slice(2); // format the anchor id
        var wrapper = '<a href="' + wrapper_id +'">';       
        $(e.nextSibling).wrap(wrapper);

    });});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [jQuery comments() plugin](http://www.bennadel.com/index.cfm?dax=blog:1563.view) to fetch comments from HTML. Usage:

```
var comments = $( "#sample" ).comments();
console.log( comments.html() );
```